# unclickable element / actions with dynamic visibility

Tags: java, internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm evaluating Selenium2 for a project on Internet Explorer 9 and I chose the mercedes-benz website because it uses AJAX and some inline popups, so I wrote a little test.

1. goto mercedes-benz.ch
2. click onto the "A", then select "Konfigurator" in the displayed overlay
3. click onto "Weiter >"
4. click onto "> Rate ändern" and the popup will show up.
5. click the "i" button in the popup

I have 2 problems in my example code:

- 1st: How to build an Actions-Chain with dynamic content that is not yet available when building the chain
  (ie. moveToElement(A).moveToElement(B): A makes B visibile, so upon building, B does not exist)
- 2nd: This is the img-element enclosed in an a-element, that I want to click:

> ```
> <a onclick="var cf = function(){ openInfo('InsurancePpi'); return false;};
> var oamSF = function(){ return oamSubmitForm('calcForm','calcForm:j_id31');};
> return (cf()==false) ? false : oamSF();" href="#">
> <img src="images/mb/btn_info_rb.gif">
> </a>
> ```

but .click() doesn't do anything. The click seems executed, but nothing happens where a popup should be shown. If I use .sendKeys(Keys.Enter) instead of .click() it works just fine.

my example code:

```
package org.test.demo;   
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class TestStep_DebugChangeRate {
    public void test() {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("http://www.mercedes-benz.ch");

        WebElement btnA = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='A']"));
        // first problem, i cannot combine moveToElement(btnA) and
        // moveToElement(btnKonfigurator), because btnKonfigurator is not
        // visible at the moment of building the Action which will then fail
        // in NoSuchElement, that's why I cheat with sendKeys(), any tips?
        (new Actions(driver))
            .moveToElement(btnA)
            .click(btnA)
            .sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
            .sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
            .sendKeys(Keys.TAB)
            .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
            .build()
            .perform();        

        performWaitBool(driver, PerformWaitExpectedConditions.isPageLoadFinished(), "timeout waitForPageLoad");
        WebElement btnContinue = driver.findElement(By.id("vsAppLnkContinue1"));
        btnContinue.click();

        performWaitBool(driver, PerformWaitExpectedConditions.isPageLoadFinished(), "timeout waitForPageLoad");
        WebElement btnChangeRate = driver.findElement(By.id("vsAppLnkPcnChangeRate"));
        btnChangeRate.click();

        performWaitBool(driver, PerformWaitExpectedConditions.isPageLoadFinished(), "timeout waitForPageLoad");
        WebElement frameInline = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='contentsC']/iframe"));
        WebDriver frame = driver.switchTo().frame(frameInline);
        WebElement btnInfoPpi = frame.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'InsurancePpi')]/img"));
        // does not throw an error, though the info popup is not opened
        btnInfoPpi.click();

        Boolean isDisplayed = btnInfoPpi.isDisplayed(); // true
        int elementWidth = btnInfoPpi.getSize().getWidth(); // 23
        btnInfoPpi.sendKeys(Keys.Enter); // this will open the popup however
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your problem with the img I would try to execute the relevant js from inside the a tag via

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("script;");
```

Further I can't help cuz the page is not working for me.
Try using Selenium IDE to get the core of your actions. Export that as Java Junit4 webdriver testcase. that might help you find your solution.

Comment: my main concern is that Selenium Webdriver is at fault here. Since i am testing a website, i cannot executeScript because I need to simulate a user and so it must be a click onto the image. If the image has no <A> around it, the test will pass, but its not right.

Selenium IDE did the same thing, simply identify the element and send a .click(). which does not work with selenium for some mysterious reason :(

Comment: executing the script that is executed when the user pushes the button is the same as if a user pushed the button. It is a workaround of course. I am not that firm with IE tests since for me Firefox works better ;-) With the IDE you cant really tell what it does behind the scenes. Because the code it generates often is not working the same way the IDE Test does.